# Is it possible to sort Sections?

Tags: best-practice

I now have 5 Structures that belong together (they are all different parts of our restaurant menu) together with my other structures its all very confusing. So what I want is a way to split up my
`----Structures----`

in the entries area to have like:

```
-----Singles------
  ..
-----Channels-----
  ..
----Structures----
  ..  
-----FoodMenu-----
  ..  
----Navigation----
  ..
```

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: Just curious, why did you split the food menu into several structures and didn't use parent entries ("Burgers", "Beers", ...) and list them all in one structure?

Comment: I started with that, but we have different menus that share some items and our weekly menu are also all from one pool of dishes. So I ended up using the entry-fieldtype to select the items for the menu and it seemed easier to have soups ands salads seperated espeacially when the plan is that someone else manages the site

Comment: The entry field type needs other filters than section. In this case it'd be nice to select the parent entry, entry type or category would also be nice to have!

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow

Comment: The reason why you're using multiple structures is that you can limit the entries available to your entries field to be from a specific structure. If there were other filters available, e.g. to show only those entries that are children of a select entry or if they belong to a category, you would have the same benefits to filter the entries shown but you wouldn't have to use multiple structures. I hope this makes sense now :)

Comment: so you're saying there is a feature missing right ?

Comment: Yep and because P+T already knows about that there's hope this gets implemented in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is at the moment, but you could probably build a easy plugin to do that with Javascript.